# Manufacturing locations of cotton swabs

Tags: data-request, geospatial, products, industry

I was wondering if the manufacturing locations of cotton swab brands/ companies had been curated. For example where are q-tips manufactured? USA?

Comment: Neither free nor open, the data is at least available to some extent from https://www.thomasnet.com/products/cotton-swabs-81413007-1.html